# Why can't I add any game I want to NVIDIA GeForce Experience?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I just got this GeForce 680 GTX and am trying to add a few games to it, but it only seems to let me add folders which it then scans for games that it explicitly supports.  With my 570 GTX, I had a more advanced control panel where I could actually browse directly to a game's EXE and set all kinds of cool options like AA, AF, vsync, etc.  I don't like this GeForce Experience at all.  Where is the old interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out where it is.  Instead of deleting the question, I'll just answer it since help for this is very minimal.

You need to go to NVIDIA control panel (you should be able to get to this easily by right-clicking on desktop or looking in your system tray).

Click on Manage 3D settings (even though another option is actually highlighted).  There you can add actual EXEs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GeForce Experience is so that you can download recommended presets from NVIDIA for your games for your specific video card. As you've noticed, you can tweak things further in the NVIDIA Control Panel, but the settings that you get via GeForce Experience should server as a good first pass. And also as you've noticed, NVIDIA doesn't track every game out there, so it won't list everything either.